Running Totals are correct but on the wrong record
I have a running total on a group level that is based on the following evaluation formula:
whileprintingrecords;
{fieldname} in [condition]
The totals are correct, but they appear on the records below them.  For example, in the screenshot, the 6 should be on the same record as the 81, the 3 on the 87, etc.  My running total is in the group footer.  Why would this be happening?  TIA :-)

Tried moving the running total to group header and other groups.  didn't work.  I also tried doing the formula's that were on other posts here.  That didn't work either.  One formula had the condition with a variable.  I couldn't summarize the variable as it didn't show in the running total list of fields.

Are the fields that print the values for each column in the same section?  It may help if you could share more about the design of your report, focusing on what fields are in the specific sections.  If they are different sections, then you will need to use the overlay setting found in Section Expert.
